# Semantic error in Python. Mathematical mistake

Tags: python, polygon

I am trying to write a program in Python to calculate the area of a polygon. The formula is :

```
area = n * s * a / 2
a = s / 2 * tan(pi/n)
```

My code is:

```
import math

def area(s,n):
    a = s/(2* math.tan((math.pi/n)))
    b = (n*s*a)/2
    return b
```

The problem is that it calculates a total different thing. For example: area (2,5) = 3.63, when it is really 6.887.

Does anyone see a mistake?

Comment: Does it help to use 2.0 instead of 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import math

def area(s,n):
    a = s/(2* math.tan((math.pi/n)))
    b = (n*s*a)/2
    return b

area(2, 5)
#>>> 6.881909602355868

def area(s,n):
    a = s/2* math.tan((math.pi/n))
    b = (n*s*a)/2
    return b

area(2, 5)
#>>> 3.6327126400268046
```

Really though, don't use single letter names. Making things unreadable does nobody any good.

If your mathematics doesn't make semantic sense, rewrite it so that it does. Your confusion is a testament to this.